# How to assign Pandas series as column names?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to assign `treatment_col` Pandas series as the column names of the last 30 columns of `df` dataframe.

My attempt:

```
df.columns[-30:] = treatment_col
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-191-81e2b2a6c645> in <module>()
      1 # Assign treatment_col as column names of unlabelled columns
----> 2 df.columns[-30:] = treatment_col # The last 30 columns are treatment columns

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   4583     @final
   4584     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
-> 4585         raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
   4586 
   4587     def __getitem__(self, key):

TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

`df` (as dictionary)

```
df.iloc[1:3,].to_dict()

{'Cytoband': {'---': '---'},
 'Entrez Gene': {'---': '---'},
 'GO Biological Process': {'---': nan},
 'GO Cellular Component': {'---': nan},
 'GO Molecular Function': {'---': nan},
 'GO_biological_process': {'---': '---'},
 'GO_cellular_component': {'---': '---'},
 'GO_molecular_function': {'---': '---'},
 'Gene Title': {'---': '---'},
 'Pathway': {'---': nan},
 'Probe ID': {'---': '7892503'},
 'Protein Domains': {'---': nan},
 'Swiss-Prot': {'---': '---'},
 'UniGene': {'---': nan},
 'category': {'---': 'normgene->intron'},
 'crosshyb_type': {'---': '---'},
 'gene_assignment': {'---': '---'},
 'mrna_assignment': {'---': '--- // --- // neg_control // --- // --- // --- // --- // --- // ---'},
 nan: {'---': '4.52'},
 'pathway': {'---': '---'},
 'protein_domains': {'---': '---'},
 'seqname': {'---': '---'},
 'start': {'---': '---'},
 'stop': {'---': '---'},
 'strand': {'---': '---'},
 'swissprot': {'---': '---'},
 'total_probes': {'---': '4'},
 'unigene': {'---': '---'}}
```

`treatment_col`

```
0
12    12_P1_T4_TimeC2_PIDC4_Non-Survivor
48    48_P1_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Non-Survivor
4      4_P1_T2_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor
8      8_P1_T3_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor
0      0_P1_T1_TimeC1_PIDC4_Non-Survivor
24    24_P1_T5_TimeC4_PIDC4_Non-Survivor
24        24_P2_T5_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor
4          4_P2_T2_TimeC2_PIDC1_Survivor
12        12_P2_T4_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor
0          0_P2_T1_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor
8          8_P2_T3_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor
48        48_P2_T6_TimeC3_PIDC3_Survivor
0          0_P3_T1_TimeC1_PIDC1_Survivor
12        12_P3_T4_TimeC2_PIDC1_Survivor
4          4_P3_T2_TimeC2_PIDC1_Survivor
8          8_P3_T3_TimeC4_PIDC1_Survivor
24        24_P3_T5_TimeC3_PIDC1_Survivor
48        48_P3_T6_TimeC3_PIDC1_Survivor
24        24_P5_T5_TimeC3_PIDC3_Survivor
8          8_P5_T3_TimeC4_PIDC3_Survivor
12        12_P5_T4_TimeC2_PIDC3_Survivor
0          0_P5_T1_TimeC4_PIDC3_Survivor
48        48_P5_T6_TimeC3_PIDC3_Survivor
4          4_P5_T2_TimeC2_PIDC3_Survivor
48        48_P4_T6_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor
0          0_P4_T1_TimeC1_PIDC1_Survivor
12        12_P4_T4_TimeC2_PIDC2_Survivor
24        24_P4_T5_TimeC3_PIDC2_Survivor
8          8_P4_T3_TimeC4_PIDC1_Survivor
dtype: object
```

`treatment_col` is a Pandas series:

```
type(treatment_col)

pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all dataframe column names on a temporary array first, then assign the new ones to the subset of array.

```
columns = df.columns.values
columns[-30:] = treatment_col.values
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: It raised `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (29,) into shape (30,)`. I need all the 30 columns, so `columns[-29:]` is not an option.

Comment: you need to recheck number of new column names

Comment: `len(df.columns)` is 57

Comment: I meant `treatment_col`. `treatment_col` has 29 elements, right? From your question above, the first one is blank (i.e. index 0).

Comment: So, it supposes to be `[-29:]`.

Comment: But I need all the columns. `[-29:]` will leave one column empty

Comment: Because one name is missing from your `treatment_col`. It is not a problem with my solution but your data.